# WebScraping w/ Beautiful Soup: How to Return an Empty Element in a List?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull information on discounted products from [this](https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Productsperpage/120?id=16499) link. Currently, the results are being returned in a list using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver #need to be able to quit out of the brower
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
opts = Options()
opts.headless=True
assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get(https://www.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-blazers-sports-coats/Productsperpage/120?id=16499)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
discount = []
for tag in soup.find_all(class_='discount'):
   discount.append(tag.text.strip())
print(discount)
browser.quit()
print('The program is terminated')
```

If a product isn't on sale, how could I return an element in the list like "N/A" or "Not on Sale"? Definitely will be some kind of if/else statement, but I'm not sure what the condition would be.

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Note: `find_All()` method is deprecated in beautiful soup 4. Which is replaced by `find_all()`
The correct syntax for using method `find_all('p', class_='class_name')`

Below is for only beautiful soup 3
Try this replace `soup.find_all(class_='discount')` with `soup.findAll("span", {"class": "discount"})`.

Comment: Why replacing the method name with a deprecated one?

Comment: check date bro and this was serving my purpose well

Comment: Not sure what you want to say here. The answer is from 2020 and the non-deprecated method names where introduced in January 2014.  Sure one doesn't need to change the names in existing code right away, but over 5 years later still using deprecated aliases in new code isn't really a good idea.  Those aliases will go away eventually.

Comment: My bad again as i said at that moment it was full filling my purpose so I didn’t bother to check it’s deprecated let confirm with my dev team and update my answer

Comment: Please can share the reference link also that would be great help for us thanks

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience i finally went through docs and found that i was using beautiful soup 3 not 4 in 4 it was deprecated